# Listas enlazadas en C ¿Cómo insertar elementos en una lista enlazada?

Tags: c, lista, punteros, nodos

Tengo que hacer una lista enlazada de nodos. Estoy intentando rellenarla pero no funciona ¿alguna idea de lo que estoy haciendo mal?

Las estructuras que uso son:

```
#define MAXCAR 30

typedef char Cadena[MAXCAR+1];

typedef struct TPersona
{
    int Codigo;
    Cadena Nombre;
} TPERSONA;

typedef struct TNodo
{
    TPERSONA dato;
    struct TNodo *siguiente;
} TNODO;

typedef struct TLista
{
    TNODO *cabecera;
} TLISTA;
```

Debo leer los datos de un fichero (por ello el fscanf() de después). Eso lo hace correctamente. Pero no va insertando los nodos que voy creando en la lista.

Para ir insertando los nodos en la lista:

```
for(int i=0; !feof(f); i++)
    {
        TNODO *puntero=crearNodo();  //Se declara un nodo
        fscanf(f,"%d %s %s", &puntero->dato.Codigo, puntero->dato.Nombre); 
//Guardo los datos del empleado en el nodo
        if((lista->cabecera)==NULL)  //Si me pasan una lista vacia
        {
            puntero=lista->cabecera;
            puntero->siguiente=NULL;

        }
        else //Si hay mas elementos en la lista
        {
            while(puntero!=NULL)  //recorro la lista hasta el final
            {
                puntero=puntero->siguiente;
            }
            puntero=puntero->siguiente;// Meto al final de la lista el nuevo nodo
            puntero->siguiente=NULL;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Deberías por si acaso publicar también la función crearNodo().Con respecto al código que muestras, en el caso de que no sea el primer elemento, pones la condición de que mientras el puntero!= null, pero ese puntero (a falta de ver cómo lo has creado con la función),no debería ser null en ningún caso.En defintiiva,debes de crear en todos los casos un puntero (que no es el que has creado),que apunte al comienzo de la línea, y ese será el que diga si es primer elemeno o no, y será el que vayas moviendo.Luego,cuando tengas la posición del último elemento, lo usas para apuntar con el puntero creado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esta asignación:

```
if((lista->cabecera)==NULL)  //Si me pasan una lista vacia
{
    puntero=lista->cabecera; // <<--- AQUI
    puntero->siguiente=NULL;
}
```

Está al revés. No tienes que modificar `puntero`, sino `lista->cabecera`:

```
lista->cabecera = puntero;
```

Por otro lado, el código para añadir nuevos elementos también está mal:

```
while(puntero!=NULL)  //recorro la lista hasta el final
{
    puntero=puntero->siguiente;
}
puntero=puntero->siguiente;// Meto al final de la lista el nuevo nodo
puntero->siguiente=NULL;
```

Y el motivo es exactamente el mismo que teníamos antes... estás atacando a `puntero` en vez de modificar `lista->cabecera`:

```
TNodo nodo* = lista->cabecera;
while(nodo->siguiente != NULL)  //recorro la lista hasta el final
{
    nodo=nodo->siguiente;
}
nodo->siguiente = puntero;// Meto al final de la lista el nuevo nodo
puntero->siguiente=NULL;
```

Como ves, lo que hacemos es crear un puntero `nodo` que apunta al inicio de la lista enlazada. A continuación usamos dicho puntero para colocarnos en el último nodo de la lista para, finalmente, añadir el nuevo nodo al final de la lista.